# Why is my Variable Value Being Doubled Visual C#

Tags: c#

Please don't hate me too much if this ends up being a simple solution, I've just been sitting here for a good while trying to figure out what the deal is with it.

To start off with, here's my problem: I'm passing the CheckBox and a constant variable into this function. It was purely so that I didn't have to rewrite the code for 8 different CheckBoxes that are basically built the same.

For whatever reason, whenever I try to use the += operator on the pricedOptionsTotal and totalPrice in this function, it seems to double what's passed into it with y. For example, if I pass 0.15 as y into the function, it'll get displayed as 0.30.

I've tried doing things locally in the function, I've tried have it return the value. I've tried just doing it in the generated CheckBox function in the form. I have similar code with some RadioButtons, and the code in there is working perfectly fine.

This is the function I'm talking about:

```
private void IfChecked(CheckBox x, double y)
{
    if(x.Checked == true)
    {
        //Add to the private global variable
        pricedOptionsTotal += (decimal)y;
        totalPrice += (decimal)y;
    }
    else if(x.Checked == false) //Check if it was just unchecked
    {
        //Remove Y from the totals
        pricedOptionsTotal -= (decimal)y;
        totalPrice -= (decimal)y;
    }

    if (pricedOptionsTotal > 0) //Display the pricedOptionsTotal sum in a currency format
    {
        displayPricedOptions.Text = "Add " + pricedOptionsTotal.ToString("C");
    }
    else
    {
        displayPricedOptions.Text = " "; //Reset textBox
    }
}
```

These are my variables:

```
//Constant price for the base costs
private const double baseCost = 3.00; //Base cost of a burger is $3, comes with Cheddar, Swiss, or American cheese
private const double extraCheese = 0.15; //Increases the cost for more cheese.
private const double friedEgg = 0.50; //Cost of adding a Fried Egg
private const double withBacon = 0.50; //Cost of adding bacon
private const double spicyBurger = 0.75; //Cost of using special spices to make it spicy
private const double withGuacamole = 0.25; //Cost of guacamole
private const double doublePaddy = 1.00; //Cost of adding another beef paddy to the burger

//Constant price for the discount
private const double discount = 0.10; //10% discount

//Constant price for the fries
private const double sideOfFries = 3.00; //Cost of a side of fries

//Private price of priced options holder
decimal pricedOptionsTotal = 0.00m; //Price that gets displayed

//Private price of fries to use when calculating total
private decimal pricedFriesOption = 0.00m; //Fries that get displayed and added to total

//Private total price
private decimal totalPrice = (decimal)baseCost;
```

It's starting to make me think that my code is cursed or something.

Example Image
[image]

---

EDIT:
So I've sort of figured it out now. Through the power of Breakpoint (Thank you @mjwills for that reminder), I have discovered that the function works as intended. The problem now, it seems, is that once the function finishes running, the CheckedChanges seems to be running one more time. Meaning the function is forced for an additional time to run.

Breakpoint before issue:
[image]

It returns to the CheckedChanged generated code for the CheckBox: 
[image]

Before finally going through the function again and bringing it to the conclusion of doubling my 0.15 to 0.30. Like so: 
[image]

I don't know why it's doing that with these CheckBoxes. The function definitely isn't the cause with it, otherwise I wouldn't have been receiving any message and the program would've been stuck in a loop. It's confusing to me as to why it's doing this.

I have RadioButtons in this program, and similar code with it as well, and it's working fine.

Comment: The best way to attack these kinds of problems is to change the field to a property with a backing field. Then, put a breakpoint inside the setter of the property. Run the code. Invariably, the code is being set somewhere where you weren't expecting it to. The breakpoint will help you find that code.

Comment: Where are you calling IfChecked from?

Comment: I think I figured it out, relatively. It seems like the code repeats the function after it runs the first time. @mjwills Thank you by the way. I never really used breakpoint much before now, so probably going to be using it more. I just now need to figure out why it's repeating the function.

Comment: I'm running it from the Visual Studio generated "private void DoubleMeat_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)" CheckBox in the Form1.cs. @geometrikal

Comment: Just a small hint - use `decimal` rather than `double` for monetary values.

Comment: I probably should've included that, but I actually did use decimal values originally. I returned it back to them though after I found out why it's becoming 0.30 instead of 0.15.

For some reason, the function loops one more time before ending. And I haven't coded any loop for this program. @Enigmativity Thank you though.

Comment: @TylerPease `DoubleMeat_CheckedChanged` this event should be not be raised twice for one check box action (checking or un-checking). It can be the case, when you check on checkbox and programatically uncheck other checkbox. but that time too you should be decreasing the value. go through the code again.

Comment: @Amit I don't have the function raised twice for the action, or at least I don't believe.
`private void ExtraCheeseOption_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      IfChecked(extraCheeseOption, extraCheese);
}`
With the checkboxes themselves, they're not supposed to uncheck another's, but they're supposed to add to a total. When unchecked, they should remove their contribution to the total.

I had recently tried returning the message from the function as a string to the TextBox, but instead of actually returning it looped the function again before returning.

Comment: Sort of understanding it a little more. Once the function hits `displayPricedOptions.Text = "Add " + pricedOptionsTotal.ToString("C");` the function does correctly end, it's just for some reason CheckedChanged decides to repeat itself, and it runs the code again.

Comment: @TylerPease use call stack to figure out from where the second call of `IfChecked` is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Amit and @mjwills for the assistance. Because of your help (and a reminder of the fact that breakpoint exists, also @Amit I'll probably be using Call Stack more when debugging, relatively new to Visual Studio), I was able to discover that it was being called twice in the Events for the CheckBoxes. Once in CheckedChanged AND CheckStateChanged. Apparently, I had decided to put the CheckBox_CheckedChanged call in both events. Really embarrassing on my part.

[Woops.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Ri6.png)